# How to parse date and time according to PC's regional setting

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, localization

I'm using .NET Framework 4 and WPF.

My application needs to be aware of PC regional setting. It should be able to parse date and time format which is specified in regional setting in PC. Target platform in Windows 7.

My PC culture is set to en-US. To test my application, from the PC regional setting, I've set date and time format as follows:

> Short date: M/d/yyyy
>
> Long date: dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
>
> Short Time: HHmm
>
> Long Time: HHmm.ss

Now, given a string `6/3/2013 1617.18` my application should be able to successfully parse it to a date time object which represents the date and time `3rd June, 2013 4:17:18 PM`. Note that this format can be changed by the user so I can't assume this format will be used.

I've tried the following code:

```
string sdt = "6/3/2013 1617.18";
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTime dt;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParse(sdt,
                                   culture.DateTimeFormat,
                                   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                                   out dt);
```

But `validDate` is `false` after the execution.

Given a date time string formatted according to the pattern set in PC regional setting, how can I convert it to equivalent `DateTime` object?

Comment: What is the `culture.DateTimeFormat`? The date you have seems to be composed of `Short date` + `Long time`, not two shorts or two longs...

Comment: Try using DateTime.Parse() to do this. It will throw an exception which you can catch and the interpret.

Comment: @Oded: please note that the date time format is actually variable. user can set it as s/he wish. of course, the date time formats for my PC is in the question (Short date, Long date, Short Time, Long Time).